# How do I auto-reset exposed filters?

Tags: 7, views, search

I am using views along with solr search api to display search results. Within results I need to add filters so I have used views exposed filter for the indexed fields. Now that I have exposed filter I am trying to reset all views exposed filters every time when someone tries to search something in the search field.

How do I achieve this?

I am using **Search: Fulltext search (exposed)** exposed filter to search for keywords using views.

Answer (score 0):

In exposed form settings enable reset button and give label save it you will get reset button